# Tableau Desktop client has to talk to Tableau server

Tags: desktop, tableau-api

Tableau architecture shows that Desktop connects to tableau server (using gateway) and then to data server which are on tableau server. My question is do tableau client has to talk to tableau server? Can't I just install tableau desktop and connect to required database (even hosted on cloud)?

Regards, G.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tableau supports multiple approaches for connecting to data.

Tableau Desktop can indeed connect directly to a database without Tableau Server being involved at all. This is a typical way to start and often remains the main approach.

You can also choose to use Tableau Server as an effective proxy to your database, and have multiple desktop and server clients connect that way. There are advantages for governance and performance to that approach in some case.

You can mix and match approaches for different data sources, and there are some other middle ground approaches such as to store an extract on Tableau Server, which acts conceptually like a very fast read-only materialized view which you can then refresh on a schedule of your choices.

Comment: In addition to the governance and performance reasons, use of Tableau Server as a proxy means that database drivers do not need to be installed on client machines running Tableau Desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Tableau Desktop is a stand alone product. You can use Tableau Desktop without the server.

You are able to connect to database directly and you have a lot of choices, such as MySQL, Oracle, Teradata and also cloud, such as Amazon Redshift, Google big query, Google Cloud SQL, Spark SQL

[image: Tableau Connect]

Answer (score 0):

Tableau has the following products:

1. Tableau Desktop
2. Tableau Server
3. Tableau Online
4. Tableau Reader (free)
5. Tableau Public (free)

> My question is do tableau client has to talk to tableau server?

- The "Tableau Client" that you refer to could be either a web browser or Tableau Reader.  The web browser has to talk to Tableau Server, but Tableau Reader requires the extracted Tableau Workbook.

> Can't I just install tableau desktop and connect to required database
>   (even hosted on cloud)?

- You can, but you will lose measures, dimensions, filters, formatting, sets etc. which is local to the cloud tableau sheet.
- You can download workbook in tbxw format to play with